# How To Benchmark a processor model?

Tags: benchmarking, microprocessors

I know benchmarks are programs written to test processor performance in detail (Memory Operations, MIPS, FLOPS, etc).

Are any of these programs available for download and use (as source code)? If yes how to use them? Are they just compile and run? Or do they need some profiling or other work to be done?

Comment: Running real-world programs or looking at peak flops values and branching/caching capabilities? Some need more cache some need more branching some need more flops while some needs real-time computing. Memory is usually limiting. Sometimes you look at benchmarks to buy a cpu but a new game may not utilize it fully.

Comment: peak flops values and branching/caching capabilities. and I'm not talking about benchmarking an available processor or choosing one to buy. I'm talking about testing a processor model or processor architecture, find its pros and cons and testing its performance and so on.

Comment: "Are any of these programs available for download and use?" You can look at clbenchmark dot com and sisoft sandra sites they do a lot of tests covering many fields and their database may be satisfactory.

Comment: Those are precompiled programs for specific architectures not source codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a little bit of search, there are many open source benchmarks available for download as source code.

[Wikipedia List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_%28computing%29#Open_source_benchmarks)

[Roy Longbottom's PC Benchmark Collection](http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/)

[netlib Collection](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/)

Answer (score 0):

If we're compiling a list, here are some other links commonly used, mostly graph algorithms:

- [Graph500](http://www.graph500.org/)
- [LoneStar](http://iss.ices.utexas.edu/?p=projects/galois/lonestar)
- Another, more simplified one, with quite a lot of basic algorithms - [Problem Based Benchmark Suite](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pbbs/benchmarks.html)

For server oriented workloads, you can also use [MemcacheD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)